# Developing Grafana Datasource

Tags: javascript, datasource, grafana

I wanna build my own datasource to show data in a grafana graph. Now, I testing the fake simple json in grafana, to figure out how the things work behind the scenes. I have this code, which query the data I wanna show in grafana:

```
query(options) {
    var query = this.buildQueryParameters(options);
    query.targets = query.targets.filter(t => !t.hide);

    if (query.targets.length <= 0) {
      return this.q.when({data: []});
    }

    console.log('query Return: ');
    console.log(this.doRequest({url: this.url + '/query',data: query,method: 'POST'}));
    console.log('\n');

    var teste = this.doRequest({
      url: this.url + '/query',
      data: query,
      method: 'POST'
    });

    console.log('teste Return: ');
    console.log(teste);
    console.log('\n');
    return teste;
  }
```

And, I receive that return : 
[result of console.log(teste)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcOYx.png)

How can I access the teste.$$state.value.data["0"].datapoints["0"] for example?

If I tried to access teste or teste.$$state, that's ok. But when I try teste.$$state.pur or any attributes in the teste.$$state tree I got an *undefined* response.

Answer (score 2):

Im quite sure your request is async, so to check the results you need to use a callback:

```
var teste = this.doRequest({
    url: this.url + '/query',
    data: query,
    method: 'POST'
}, function(result){
    console.log(result) <----- 
});
```

or [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) if a Promise is returned:

```
var teste = this.doRequest({
    url: this.url + '/query',
    data: query,
    method: 'POST'
}).then(function(result){
    console.log(result) <-----
});
```